# How do I set the product price to 2 decimal places, it's 4 digit now when i search product in search option

Tags: magento

When i search any product in search bar it's showing 4 digits after decimal number how can i fix it, i want just 2 digit after decimal.

Comment: you can use helper  method to achieve this. add a helper method that fix 2 decimal points for price. Then using that helper function display your price.

Comment: Any custom extension to show products list when you search ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this helper

```
    $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

I hope this helps.